# Login but didn't push to home in flutter using firebase

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, authentication

i'm new with flutter, so i have little problem that i tried to log in with firebase but it's not push to home when i click button, but i can get data with createUserWithEmailAndPassword. i tried alot of time to fix it but it's didn't work. Difficultly i can't find any error in debug console So i don't know what's wrong with my code. How ever please kindly help and advertise me to solve this problem.

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firstproject/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Home',
    home: Login(),
  ));
}

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(   
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //user log in
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Home();
          } else {
            return const Login();
          }
        },
      ),
      //drawer: const MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Login.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
// import 'firebase_options.dart'
import 'package:firstproject/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


// ignore: camel_case_types
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
    final Uri uri = Uri(scheme: "https", host: url);
    if (!await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
      throw "can not launch URL";
    }
  }

  // void signinUser() async {
  //   await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  //       email: _email.text, password: _password.text);
  // }

  //sign in btn
  void SignUserIn() {}
  bool _validateEmail = false;
  bool _validatePassword = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 234, 234),
      body: const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          //------------------------- Email Address------------------//
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 350,
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                          //color: Color(0xff117A65),
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 0.5,
                        )),

                        labelText: 'Email Address',
                        errorText:
                            _validateEmail ? "Please enter your email" : null,
                        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                          //color: Color(0xff117A65),
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                        // icon: const Icon(
                        //   Icons.contact_mail,
                        //   color: Color(0xff117A65),
                        // ),
                        hintText: 'Enter your email address',
                        //hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                      controller: emailController,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 350,
                      child: TextField(
                        obscureText: true, //Covert password to *
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              //color: Color(0xff117A65),
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          labelText: 'Password',
                          errorText: _validatePassword
                              ? "Please enter your email"
                              : null,
                          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                            //color: Color(0xff117A65),
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                          // icon: const Icon(
                          //   Icons.lock,
                          //   color: Color(0xff117A65),
                          // ),
                          hintText: 'Enter your password',
                          //hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                        ),
                        controller: passwordController,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          //------------------------- Button------------------//
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: emailController.text.trim(),
                            password: passwordController.text.trim());

                        // //validate message
                        // setState(() {
                        //   _email.text.isEmpty
                        //       ? _validateEmail = true
                        //       : _validateEmail = false;
                        //   _password.text.isEmpty
                        //       ? _validatePassword = true // ? = if, : = else
                        //       : _validatePassword = false;
                        // });
                      },
                      child: Column(children: const <Widget>[
                        //Icon(Icons.add),
                        Text(
                          'Log in',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          // ---------------------- Sign up -------------------
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'New one this app?',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text(
                  '  Sign up',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: emailController.text.trim(),
                      password: passwordController.text.trim());
                  // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  //       return const register();
                  //     },
                  //   ),
                  // );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                  return const Home();
                } else {
                  return const Login();
                }
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: i'm sorry to say this but it's still not work after i clicked button

Comment: Try to check the snapshot.data by adding a print statement. Check if it returns something once you press the button. Also check if the user is created in Firebase.

Comment: i'll try and let you know next

Comment: print statement is work but when i apply firebase in, it's still not go into file what i want to push

Comment: ​ @Flutter With NAS  after i clicked login it's direct to firebase_auth.dart where show me code: Future<UserCredential> signInWithEmailAndPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      return UserCredential._(
        this,
        await _delegate.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthMultiFactorExceptionPlatform catch (e) {
      throw FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException._(this, e);
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow; <==== here
    }
  }